# Android share link not available after opening the app

Tags: android, firebase-dynamic-links

I am making an android app where there is a option to share my app. I am using firebase dynamic link. In firebase console I create a dynamic link like example.page.link. In android app I create a method to create the dynamic link programmatically.The share link is created successfully. But when i click on the link to open the app, the PendingDynamicLinkData become null.

```
private Uri createDynamicLink(){
        DynamicLink dynamicLink =  FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance() 
                .createDynamicLink()                                                       
                .setLink(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/"))
                .setDomainUriPrefix("https://example.page.link")
                .setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters
                .Builder().build())
                .buildDynamicLink();
        Uri dynamicLinkUri = dynamicLink.getUri();
        Log.d(TAG+"_link",dynamicLinkUri.toString());
        return dynamicLinkUri;
}



private void getDynamicLink(){
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new         OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>(){
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                    Uri deepLink = null;
                    if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                        deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                        Log.d(TAG+"_link",deepLink.toString());
                    }else{
                        Log.d(TAG+"_link","Error");

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
                }
            });
}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml I add

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
           <data
               android:host="example.page.link"
               android:scheme="https"/>
 </intent-filter>
```